# Specflow ComparetoSet throwAnErrorDetailingWhichItemsAreMissing

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I am new to SpecFlow and trying to utilize BDD pattern using SpecFlow integrated with Visual studio 2015. 
I have a composite/complex object so that way hierarchy works is for example

```
ResponseMessage
    ---- MessageHeaderClass ContextToken
              ----This property holds a class object which will have few string properties

    ---- SomeConcreteClass MessageBody
              ----This property holds a class object which will have few string properties
```

I have written my scenario and i want to actually find the values i am getting but i am not even reaching to that point so i thought let's try to utilise ComparetoSet
method of Spec Flow Assist helper but i am getting exception and in the message of exception 
all i got this

```
| ContextToken  | MessageBody |
    + | MessageHeaderClass | SomeConcreteClass |
```

What i was expecting and i maybe wrong that ComparetoSet will set the values returned from the object to those properties mentioned in scenario. I have kept the same properties name in feature too as you can see below

```
Scenario: Request From invoker Response Values Check
    Given invoker invoked MethodName
    When Request get passed to MethodName get response
    Then I get back following response
    | ContextToken  | MessageBody             |
    #| MessageHeader | SomeConcreteClass |
    #| {3/1/2016 3:38:55 PM}   |  Request received successfully          |
    #| 10085103-1618744 |  |
    #| somevalue    |                  |
    #| 00000-44144-444244-1044-441         |                  |
    #| somevalue
```

> Exception details are as follows
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist.SetComparer`1.ThrowAnErrorDetailingWhichItemsAreMissing(IEnumerable`1
>   listOfMissingItems)    at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist.SetComparer`1.CompareToSet(IEnumerable`1 set)
>   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist.SetComparisonExtensionMethods.CompareToSet[T](Table
>   table, IEnumerable`1 set)    at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved last week after a careful insight of the code and exception message which lead me to find out the issue. The issue was i forgot to mention the getter and setter (get;set;) of a property and hence specflow was complaining about it. As soon as i decorated the property correctly problem was resolved.

Hope it will help someone. I didn't think about it originally because i was getting everything else running fine.